# Which Linux CVS client provides an option to force CRLF line endings in a checkout/update?

Tags: linux, newline, cvs

We have some CVS repositories that mirror onto a read-only network drive sandbox for non-CVS Windows users to view the latest versions.  For those repositories, the commitinfo admin file is rigged to send a request to a server running on a Windows machine, triggering a CVS update.  This ensures that the Windows users see proper line endings in text files.

The IT department wants to mothball that Windows machine and move the mirror server functionality to a Linux machine, but despite all my searching, I can't figure out how to force a Linux cvs update or checkout to use Windows line endings.  The files are tagged as text files in the repository, not binary, so I think it is technically possible for a client to provide that capability.

Is there an available Linux CVS client that has a command-line option to control the handling of line-endings?

My CVS client, from "cvs --version":
Concurrent Versions System (CVS) 1.12.12 (client/server)

Comment: A quick google (you did not indicate if you even took the time to do that before asking) seems to indicate that it is not possible and you just have to run unix2dos on all the files. (Or, if binary files are present, a script that only runs unix2dos on non-binary files.)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I actually had done a lot of searching, but came up empty, except for similar recommendations to use unix2dos.  I will edit my original question, because I technically know that it is possible.  What I don't know is if there is a freely available CVS client that provides that option.

Comment: CVS has completely stopped development. 1.11.x is the latest "stable" version. 1.12.x never quite made it to stable. There has really been no development in 10 years.